# Why do I get 'execution role must be assumable' error when trying to deploy to Lambda@Edge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

I am trying to deploy to Lambda@Edge within AWS, but when I click on 'Deploy' I get this error message:

> Correct the errors below and try again.
>
> Your function's execution role must be assumable by the edgelambda.amazonaws.com service principal.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot above has been clipped to omit the text at the bottom which currently states "Lambda will add the necessary permissions for Amazon CloudFront to invoke your Lambda function from this trigger." - this statement is NOT correct.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

From the [Lambda@Edge IAM Role documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-permissions.html):

> You must create an IAM role that can be assumed by the service
> principals lambda.amazonaws.com and edgelambda.amazonaws.com. This
> role is assumed by the service principals when they execute your
> function. For more information, see Creating the Roles and Attaching
> the Policies (Console) in the topic "AWS Managed Policies for Job
> Functions" in the IAM User Guide.
>
> You add this role under the Trust Relationship tab in IAM (do not add
> it under the Permissions tab).
>
> Here's an example role trust policy:
>
> ```
> {
>    "Version": "2012-10-17",
>    "Statement": [
>       {
>          "Effect": "Allow",
>          "Principal": {
>             "Service": [
>                "lambda.amazonaws.com",
>                "edgelambda.amazonaws.com"
>             ]
>          },
>          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
>       }
>    ]
> }
> ```

Note : If you're doing this via the AWS Console then you have to refresh the browser after you update your IAM Role
Credits: from comments @AJB

Comment: Note Bene: If you're doing this via the AWS Console then you have to refresh the browser after you update your IAM Role. The console seems to somehow cache the check and keeps throwing the error even after you've adjusted the IAM Role.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I was confused because the Lambda automatically created the role but not the trust relationship.  I just needed to go into the IAM console, find the auto-generated role, and modify the trust relationship to include "edgelambda.amazonaws.com".

Comment: That is not a legal trust policy, "This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies"

Comment: Ah, I see now. You're wording is confusing. You're  either adding a role nor a policy, as you suggest. The role is automatically created when you create the lambda function. What you really mean is you're editing the lambda function's role by adding this trust policy.

Comment: @Cerin This role is copied directly from the AWS documentation I linked at the top of my answer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-permissions.html Note that it says "You add this role under the **Trust Relationship** tab in IAM (do not add it under the **Permissions** tab)."

Comment: ALSO, future readers: note this is a LIST! Your trust relationship may already be set up: but for one service, not BOTH!!!

Comment: I added edgelambda.amazonaws.com to the policy via the Trust Relationship tab in IAM (as accessed via the correct Role in the Lambda Permissions tab) and am still getting the error when I try to deploy to Lambda@Edge. Is there a propagation delay?

Comment: UPDATE: Yes, there is a delay, apparently. 12 hours later and it works.

Comment: I had to delete the generated role, since it didn't work. Created a brand new one, filled this answer in, and it mysteriously worked.

Comment: last point saved , refresh

Answer (score 17):

1. Just go to your lambda function, `Click the configuration tab` -> then `the permission tab` (from the left menu) -> `Click on your role name`
2. Then it will navigate to the relevant IAM role page.
3. `Click Trust Relationships` Tab
4. `Click on the Edit policy` button and add the content that [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53796764/1641556) mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZzEXVkVOM8 explains the issue.

Issue: 5:39
[image]

And the resolution 6:33
[image]